# Auto running jQuery method & Calling jQuery method from onClick attribute in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm struggling with jQuery. Please help me...

When loading a page, the jQuery function is automatically executed, and at the same time,
I'd like to implement this function in button click.

### [Previously]

After loading the page, the jQuery function is automatically executed immediately.

And, there is no response when clicking the button.

*html*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn_add">LookUp</button>
```

*jQuery*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(function() { 

            ..skip..

        });

</script>
```

### [Current situation]

After loading the page, the jQuery function is not automatically executed.

But It works well when clicking the button.

*html*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn_add" onclick="$(this).Lookup();">Lookup</button>
```

*jQuery*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $.fn.Lookup = function() {

            ..skip..

        };

</script>
```

### [Goal]

Keep the jQuery function running automatically after loading the page.

Implement so that the jQuery function works even when clicking the LookUp button.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is create a function for `Lookup` and then call this function during document `ready` and button click. Refer the code snippet. I would be happy to explain further if you don't understand the code.

Edit: Also `$.fn.<xyz>` should ideally be used for extending/creating generic functionality and not for specific/page specific ones.

```js
$(function(){
    //This will bind Lookup function to the button click event
    $("#btn_add").on("click", Lookup);
    //This will immediately call the Lookup function on document ready event (startup)
    Lookup();
});

function Lookup() {
  //do something
  alert("Looking up");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn_add">LookUp</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and accurate answer! You've solved my problem. There are a lot of things I don't know because I'm a beginner. Thank you so much for your answer, and have a good day :)